# New Entry Fields in Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to create a python program using tkinter in which you can adds two fields by pressing a button. Then after pressing the button the code will take the two fields and puts them in a variable. It also has two titles which are dynamically altered depending on what number field it is and is placed underneath each time.

How would I create a button which does this. My code for the entry field so far is:

```py
from tkinter import * #Import the Tkinter module
from tkinter import messagebox #Imports the message box module
from tkinter import font #Imports fonts from tkinter

count = 2

master = Tk() #Tkinter

Label(master, text="Title", font=("Helvetica", 20, "bold underline")).grid(row=0) 
Label(master, text="Subtitle 1", font=("Helvetica", 17, "bold underline")).grid(row=2) 
Label(master, text="Entry Title 1a").grid(row=3)
Label(master, text="Entry Title 1b").grid(row=4)

entry1 = Entry(master) #Entry Fields
entry2 = Entry(master)
entry1.grid(row=3, column=1) #Puts Entry fields in a certain location
entry2.grid(row=4, column=1) # ^


Label(master, text="Subtitle 2", font=("Helvetica", 17, "bold underline")).grid(row=5)
Label(master, text="Entry title 2a").grid(row=6)
q1=Label(master, text="Entry title 2b").grid(row=7)
entry3 = Entry(master) #Entry Fields
entry4 = Entry(master)

entry3.grid(row=6, column=1)
entry4.grid(row=7, column=1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you want to know how to use the values from the Entry fields for calculations.

The way you do this is with the `.get()` function. For example `entry1.get()` to get the value entered in the `entry1` field.

I used your code to create an example of how to do this:

(Edit) I changed the function of the button to create new entry fields, to access these entry fields I added the entry fields to a list, you can access the entries from this list.

```py
from tkinter import * #Import the Tkinter module
from tkinter import messagebox #Imports the message box module
from tkinter import font #Imports fonts from tkinter

count = 2

master = Tk() #Tkinter

Label(master, text="Title", font=("Helvetica", 20, "bold underline")).grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Subtitle 1", font=("Helvetica", 17, "bold underline")).grid(row=2)
Label(master, text="Entry Title 1a").grid(row=3)
Label(master, text="Entry Title 1b").grid(row=4)

entry1 = Entry(master) #Entry Fields
entry2 = Entry(master)
entry1.grid(row=3, column=1) #Puts Entry fields in a certain location
entry2.grid(row=4, column=1) # ^


Label(master, text="Subtitle 2", font=("Helvetica", 17, "bold underline")).grid(row=5)
Label(master, text="Entry title 2a").grid(row=6)
q1=Label(master, text="Entry title 2b").grid(row=7)
entry3 = Entry(master) #Entry Fields
entry4 = Entry(master)

entry3.grid(row=6, column=1)
entry4.grid(row=7, column=1)

button1 = Button(master, text="Button 1", bg="snow", command=lambda: create_entry())
button1.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=2)

global row_count, entries
row_count = 9
entries = []


def create_entry():
    global row_count, entries
    temp_entry = Entry(master)
    temp_entry.grid(row=row_count, column=1)
    entries.append(temp_entry)
    Label(master, text="Entry title " + str(row_count)).grid(row=row_count)
    row_count += 1

def entries_multiplied():
    value = 1
    global entries
    for entry in entries:
        value *= int(entry.get()) if entry.get() != "" else 1
    return value


master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry but I meant how would I create a button which adds multiple of those entry fields and makes a new variable for it each time. I have already been able to use `.get()`. What I mean was how would I create a button which creates multiple entry fields each time you pressed a button.

Comment: I will update my answer to achieve this, however I believe making a class for this type of code would make it much easy to write, I would suggest using classes for code like this in future.

Comment: (Just for clarification) How would I get the all value from the list to be multiplied together and outputted in the shell?

Comment: @Roxiun I'll add a `entriesMultiplied()` function that does that :)

Comment: How would I get an exact entry value. eg. How would I get the value from the 4th field or 6th etc.?

Comment: If you just want to get it from the ones that the button creates it would be something like `entries[0].get()` to get from the first entry field, or `entries[4].get()` to get from the fifth entry field created.